# Restarting an HLS stream from a Chromecast receiver app?

Tags: http-live-streaming, chromecast, google-cast

I'm working on a Chromecast custom receiver which uses the [Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/) to play HLS streams.  Occasionally, the transcoder creating the streams creates a glitch which causes the media library to crash when it tries to load that media segment.

While I can't do anything directly about the stream or the Chromecast device, I have been trying to add a work-around in the customer receiver in the `cast.api.player.Host` object's `onError` handler.

Seeking ahead in the stream does not seem to work as it always generates "Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable." errors from the media library.  It appears that the initial error breaks something in the source handler.

Loading the stream from scratch (with an updated currentTime value) by manually invoking `onLoad()` on the `cast.receiver.MediaManager` object does seem to work; the stream begins playing again after the crash point.

```js
// try to skip over the error
playPosition += 10.0;
console.log("attempting to seek to position: "+ playPosition);

// reuse the original load event with two changes:
// 1. the new start point is the position we want to "seek" to
loadEvent.data['currentTime'] = playPosition;

// 2. force autoload to begin playback as soon as possible
loadEvent.data['autoplay'] = true;

// fire the event
MediaManager.onLoad(loadEvent);

// what now?
```

The problem is that connected senders are not able to control this new media session. Sender attempts to stop, pause, or seek result in this warning: `Unexpected command, player is in IDLE state so the media session ID is not valid yet`.

What is the proper way of initiating playback of a stream from the receiver so that senders can be notified?

I'm using version 2.0.0 of cast_receiver.js and 0.6.0 of media_player.js

Comment: Looks like calling `setMediaInformation()` on the `cast.receiver.MediaManager` object seems to do the trick.  Anything else I'm missing?